# Upload Video Twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am developing a mobile app that share video to youtube, fb and twitter. I know there is a twitvid api but as i am fairly new to iphone development i just do not know how to make use of this.

Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unable to upload video directly to twitter, but you can upload your video to youtube and then send a shortened url to the user's status.

Comment: Hi i have got the sdk for Twitvid down and managed to upload a video but know i need to figure out how to authenticate user to twitter and then upload - would you know how to go about doing this.

Comment: Hi all i need some help. I am using the TwitVid api and keep getting an error and i just can work out why its doing this.

Comment: Hi all, how to get youtube url after uploading video on youtube. i am using gdata to upload video on youtube but i dont have any url in response to upload on twitter. Let me know if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can share video to Twitter by using [the uploading media new API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked). And I have tried it, it works.

I made a convenient class to make post video to Twitter more easily.

Please check this: https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

You just need to call this class method.

```
+(void)uploadTwitterVideo:(NSData*)videoData account:(ACAccount*)account withCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)completion;
```

Hope it can resolve your problem.